# jquery cropbox not cropping properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to crop image using jquery cropping box . [Cropbox](https://github.com/acornejo/jquery-cropbox)
This is working fine with Large squre image but not working fine with ing to small and rectangle img. I am trying to modify the library.

KINDLY REVIEW ON THE LINE NO 230 . js-cropbox.js

```js
(function() {
  // helper functions
  function is_touch_device() {
    return 'ontouchstart' in window || // works on most browsers
           'onmsgesturechange' in window; // works on ie10
  }

  function fill(value, target, container) {
    if (value + target < container)
      value = container - target;
    return value > 0 ? 0 : value;
  }

  function uri2blob(dataURI) {
      var uriComponents = dataURI.split(',');
      var byteString = atob(uriComponents[1]);
      var mimeString = uriComponents[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
      var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
      var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
      for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++)
          ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
      return new Blob([ab], { type: mimeString });
  }

  var pluginName = 'cropbox';

  function factory($) {
    function Crop($image, options) {
      this.width = null;
      this.height = null;
      this.img_width = null;
      this.img_height = null;
      this.img_left = 0;
      this.img_top = 0;
      this.minPercent = null;
      this.options = options;
      this.$image = $image;
      this.$image.hide().prop('draggable', false).addClass('cropImage').wrap('<div class="cropFrame" />'); // wrap image in frame;
      this.$frame = this.$image.parent();
      this.init();
    }

    Crop.prototype = {
      init: function () {
        var self = this;

        var defaultControls = $('<div/>', { 'class' : 'cropControls' })
              .append($('<span>Drag to crop</span>'))
              .append($('<a/>', { 'class' : 'cropZoomIn' }).on('click', $.proxy(this.zoomIn, this)))
              .append($('<a/>', { 'class' : 'cropZoomOut' }).on('click', $.proxy(this.zoomOut, this)));

        this.$frame.append(this.options.controls || defaultControls);
        this.updateOptions();

        if (typeof $.fn.hammer === 'function' || typeof Hammer !== 'undefined') {
          var hammerit, dragData;
          if (typeof $.fn.hammer === 'function')
            hammerit = this.$image.hammer();
          else
            hammerit = Hammer(this.$image.get(0));

          hammerit.on('touch', function(e) {
            e.gesture.preventDefault();
          }).on("dragleft dragright dragup dragdown", function(e) {
            if (!dragData)
              dragData = {
                startX: self.img_left,
                startY: self.img_top,
              };
            dragData.dx = e.gesture.deltaX;
            dragData.dy = e.gesture.deltaY;
            e.gesture.preventDefault();
            e.gesture.stopPropagation();
            self.drag.call(self, dragData, true);
          }).on('release', function(e) {
            e.gesture.preventDefault();
            dragData = null;
            self.update.call(self);
          }).on('doubletap', function(e) {
            e.gesture.preventDefault();
            self.zoomIn.call(self);
          }).on('pinchin', function (e) {
            e.gesture.preventDefault();
            self.zoomOut.call(self);
          }).on('pinchout', function (e) {
            e.gesture.preventDefault();
            self.zoomIn.call(self);
          });
        } else {
          this.$image.on('mousedown.' + pluginName, function(e1) {
            var dragData = {
              startX: self.img_left,
              startY: self.img_top,
            };
            e1.preventDefault();
            $(document).on('mousemove.' + pluginName, function (e2) {
              dragData.dx = e2.pageX - e1.pageX;
              dragData.dy = e2.pageY - e1.pageY;
              self.drag.call(self, dragData, true);
            }).on('mouseup.' + pluginName, function() {
              self.update.call(self);
              $(document).off('mouseup.' + pluginName);
              $(document).off('mousemove.' + pluginName);
            });
          });
        }
        if ($.fn.mousewheel) {
          this.$image.on('mousewheel.' + pluginName, function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (e.deltaY < 0)
              self.zoomIn.call(self);
            else
              self.zoomOut.call(self);
          });
        }
      },

      updateOptions: function () {
        var self = this;
        self.img_top = 0;
        self.img_left = 0;
        self.$image.css({width: '', left: self.img_left, top: self.img_top});
        self.$frame.width(self.options.width).height(self.options.height);
        self.$frame.off('.' + pluginName);
        self.$frame.removeClass('hover');
        if (self.options.showControls === 'always' || self.options.showControls === 'auto' && is_touch_device())
          self.$frame.addClass('hover');
        else if (self.options.showControls !== 'never') {
          self.$frame.on('mouseenter.' + pluginName, function () { self.$frame.addClass('hover'); });
          self.$frame.on('mouseleave.' + pluginName, function () { self.$frame.removeClass('hover'); });
        }

        // Image hack to get width and height on IE
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = self.$image.attr('src');
        img.onload = function () {
          self.width = img.width;
          self.height = img.height;
          img.src = '';
          img.onload = null;
          self.percent = undefined;
          self.fit.call(self);
          if (self.options.result)
            self.setCrop.call(self, self.options.result);
          else
            self.zoom.call(self, self.minPercent);
          self.$image.fadeIn('fast');
        };
      },

      remove: function () {
        var hammerit;
        if (typeof $.fn.hammer === 'function')
          hammerit = this.$image.hammer();
        else if (typeof Hammer !== 'undefined')
          hammerit = Hammer(this.$image.get(0));
        if (hammerit)
          hammerit.off('mousedown dragleft dragright dragup dragdown release doubletap pinchin pinchout');
        this.$frame.off('.' + pluginName);
        this.$image.off('.' + pluginName);
        this.$image.css({width: '', left: '', top: ''});
        this.$image.removeClass('cropImage');
        this.$image.removeData('cropbox');
        this.$image.insertAfter(this.$frame);
        this.$frame.removeClass('cropFrame');
        this.$frame.removeAttr('style');
        this.$frame.empty();
        this.$frame.hide();
      },

      fit: function () {
        var widthRatio = this.options.width / this.width,
          heightRatio = this.options.height / this.height;
        this.minPercent = (widthRatio >= heightRatio) ? widthRatio : heightRatio;
      },

      setCrop: function (result) {
        this.percent = Math.max(this.options.width/result.cropW, this.options.height/result.cropH);
        this.img_width = Math.ceil(this.width*this.percent);
        this.img_height = Math.ceil(this.height*this.percent);
        this.img_left = -Math.floor(result.cropX*this.percent);
        this.img_top = -Math.floor(result.cropY*this.percent);
        this.$image.css({ width: this.img_width, left: this.img_left, top: this.img_top });
        this.update();
      },

      zoom: function(percent) {
        var old_percent = this.percent;

        this.percent = Math.max(this.minPercent, Math.min(this.options.maxZoom, percent));
        this.img_width = Math.ceil(this.width * this.percent);
        this.img_height = Math.ceil(this.height * this.percent);

        if (old_percent) {
          var zoomFactor = this.percent / old_percent;
          this.img_left = fill((1 - zoomFactor) * this.options.width / 2 + zoomFactor * this.img_left, this.img_width, this.options.width);
          this.img_top = fill((1 - zoomFactor) * this.options.height / 2 + zoomFactor * this.img_top, this.img_height, this.options.height);
        } else {
          this.img_left = fill((this.options.width - this.img_width) / 2, this.img_width,  this.options.width);
          this.img_top = fill((this.options.height - this.img_height) / 2, this.img_height, this.options.height);
        }

        this.$image.css({ width: this.img_width, left: this.img_left, top: this.img_top });
        this.update();
      },
      zoomIn: function() {
        this.zoom(this.percent + (1 - this.minPercent) / (this.options.zoom - 1 || 1));
      },
      zoomOut: function() {
        this.zoom(this.percent - (1 - this.minPercent) / (this.options.zoom - 1 || 1));
      },
      drag: function(data, skipupdate) {
        this.img_left = fill(data.startX + data.dx, this.img_width, this.options.width);
        this.img_top = fill(data.startY + data.dy, this.img_height, this.options.height);
        this.$image.css({ left: this.img_left, top: this.img_top });
        if (skipupdate)
          this.update();
      },
      update: function() {
        this.result = {
          cropX: -Math.ceil(this.img_left / this.percent),
          cropY: -Math.ceil(this.img_top / this.percent),
          cropW: Math.floor(this.options.width / this.percent),
          cropH: Math.floor(this.options.height / this.percent),
          stretch: this.minPercent > 1
        };

        this.$image.trigger(pluginName, [this.result, this]);
      },
      getDataURL: function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'), ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var sourceX = this.result.cropX;
        var sourceY = this.result.cropY;
        var sourceWidth = this.result.cropW;
        var sourceHeight = this.result.cropH;
        var destWidth = this.options.width;
        var destHeight = this.options.height;
        var destX = this.result.cropX;
        var destY = this.result.cropX;
        console.log(this);
        canvas.height=this.result.cropW;
         canvas.height=this.result.cropH;

        //ctx.drawImage(this.$image.get(0), sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, 0 , 0 , destWidth, destHeight);
          ctx.drawImage(this.$image.get(0), this.result.cropX, this.result.cropY, this.result.cropW, this.result.cropH, 0, 0, this.options.width, this.options.height);
        return canvas.toDataURL();
      },
      getBlob: function () {
        return uri2blob(this.getDataURL());
      },
    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
      return this.each(function() {
        var inst = $.data(this, pluginName);
        if (!inst) {
          var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn[pluginName].defaultOptions, options);
          $.data(this, pluginName, new Crop($(this), opts));
        } else if (options) {
          $.extend(inst.options, options);
          inst.updateOptions();
        }
      });
    };

    $.fn[pluginName].defaultOptions = {
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      zoom: 10,
      maxZoom: 1,
      controls: null,
      showControls: 'auto'
    };
  }

  if (typeof require === "function" && typeof exports === "object" && typeof module === "object")
      factory(require("jquery"));
  else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd)
      define(["jquery"], factory);
  else
      factory(window.jQuery || window.Zepto);

})();
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/1.0.5/hammer.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

 <script src="jquery.cropbox.js"></script>
   <link type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="http://acornejo.github.io/jquery-cropbox/jquery.cropbox.css">
     <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {

   $("#browse").on("change",function(){
     var getCropImg=this;
      if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }

    });
     function imageIsLoaded(e) {
             $('#cropimage').attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    $('#cropimage').cropbox({
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    }).on('cropbox', function(e, data,img ) {
        var url=img.getDataURL();
        $('#preview').attr("src",url);

    });
});
</script>
<input type="file" id="browse"></input>
 <img id="cropimage" crossorigin="anonymous" alt="" src="http://css375.gaanacdn.com/images/gaana-beta-logo-v2.png" />
<div id="results"></div>
<img id="preview">
```

Comment: What is not working ? What change you are suppose to make ?

Comment: By the way thnks @Rayontry to crop small size img (36x36) or rectangle size image (200 x 500) ; you will understand . CROP is not done properly  .

Comment: May be I will, But what are you doing with the library ? What is not working as per your change ?

Comment: croping is not done properly . @Rayon :( . Wait i will show you

Comment: Can you see the changes ??